# Filter on attribute in SELECT-statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 that looks like this

```
TABLE(
    [Id] [int],
    [FK_Id] [int],
    [SequenceNumber] [smallint],
    [value] [smallint]
(
```

Id is a unique Primary Key but there are multiple rows with the same FK_Id and different sequencenumbers. I want to compare the values of the two rows with the same FK_Id and the highest SequenceNumber. Something like

```
SELECT t1.value - t2.value
From Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
On t1.FK_Id = t2.FK_Id
```

My problem is that I cant figure out how sort out so I only get the two with the highest SequenceNumber for each FK_ID, could it be done inside the SELECT statement or do I need to make it in steps?

Comment: You mean you want one result row per `FK_Id` that subtracts the one with the highest sequence number from the second highest? If not example data might help. Also how many rows per `FK_Id` are there on average?

Comment: do you wants to display the highest sequence number?

Comment: I think he wants to display the two highest sequence numbers for each unique foreign key

Comment: Thats correct Martin. The number of rows per FK_Id is between 2 and a few hundered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use rownumber and a common table expression. Have a look at my code under here.

```
with mydata (id, value, row) as
(
SELECT ID, value,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FK_ID ORDER BY Sequencenumber ASC) AS Row
FROM mytable
) select * from mydata where [row] between 1 and 2
```

Comment: Thanks! This what was I needed, just changed ASC to DESC for perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX() function

```
SELECT t1.value - t2.value
From Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
On t1.FK_Id = t2.FK_Id
```

TO

```
SELECT T1.Id, (T1.VALUE-T2.VALUE) AS VALUEMIN, MAX(T1.FK_ID) FROM TABLE T1, T2 
WHERE T1.FK_ID = T2.FK_ID
GROUP BY T1.Id
```